# Azure: getting invoice data with the BillingManagementClient class

Tags: c#, api, azure, billing

The last line of the following code results in an **"Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"** exception and I don't understand why:

Given the following code :

```
var tenantDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantDomain"];
var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"];
var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
var subscriptionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionID"];

var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantDomain, clientId, secret);
var bmc = new BillingManagementClient(serviceCreds);
bmc.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

List<Invoice> allInvoices = bmc.Invoices.List().ToList();
```

Suggestions anyone ? Should I specify a date period explicitly ? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suggestions anyone ? Should I specify a date period explicitly ? How?

If we want to access Billing we need to assign the Billing Reader role to someone that needs access to the subscription billing. We could get the detail steps for the azure official [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-manage-access). I also test the code you mentioned, there is no issue with code, if it is supported.  The following is the snippet from the official [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-manage-access).

> The Billing Reader feature is in preview, and does not yet support **enterprise** (EA) subscriptions or **non-global** clouds.

Please have a try to login [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) to check whether have access to **Access to invoice**. If you see the **Access to invoice** is disabled, it seems that the subscription type is not supported.

[image]

[image]

If you still have further questions, could [contact support](https://portal.azure.com/?#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade) to get your issue resolved quickly.

Comment: You are right, Fiddler returns the same error "UnsupportedSubscriptionType" to me. And yes, this is an Enterprise Agreement subscription. Would using the "https://consumption.azure.com/v1/enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingperiods" API be an alternative? 
I saw that on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-enterprise-api-billing-periods
If so, would you have a code example ?

Comment: I am out off office now, If I have time I will try that. You also could raise a new SO thread that will get the help from global communities.